# JPA duplicated registers while querying

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, duplicates

My `Empresa` entity have 2 nested collections mapped that way:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinTable(
        name = "bandeiras_aceitas",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "empresa_id", nullable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "bandeira_id", nullable = false)})
private List<BandeiraCartao> bandeirasAceitas;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, 
        mappedBy = "empresa")
private List<HorarioAtendimento> horariosAtendimento;
```

I actually have 12 records on `horariosAtendimento` and only 1 record inside `bandeirasAceitas`for the `Empresa` I am trying to fetch. But when I use my `find` method there are 12 records inside 'bandeirasAceitas', the problem is that the sql generated by jpa(hibernate) is duplicating the records like (number of records on `horariosAtendimento`* number of records on `bandeirasAceitas`). How can I solve this?

Comment: check carefully your db content. It cannot behave the way your described.

Comment: sorry, but I already did it before asking :(

Comment: you may see the generated sql with joined tables so the results set will include the multiple rows with same content for empresa, banderiaCartao but different HorarioAtendimento but those results rows are then collapsed when crating Empresa so you cannot have duplicates of BandeiraCartao in your list. Do you actually have 12 different objects of BandeiraCartao in your aceitas list? Each having same id and content? It is honestly impossible. Did you overwrite the equal method on your entities?

Comment: @MarcosJ.CKichel hibernate won't behave like that. May be there is duplicate entries in bandeirasAceitas only, the reason is you are using List so whenever you are adding new bandeirasAceitas then previous data also present in same List and updating same list only

Comment: I understand what you guys say, I may be doing something very wrong here, but I can grant you that there is only one single entry in bandeirasAceitas, furthermore I am somewhat used to hibernate, what makes this even more weird, anyway I am switching to a set tomorrow so I can test, it should work.